# How can I make the Entities in a ParallaxBackground move vertically in AndEngine?

Tags: java, graphics, andengine, parallax

Title says it all, currently I'm making a game where my character moves vertically and I want the ParallaxBackground entities to do the same, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to extend the ParallaxEntity contained in the ParallaxBackground class and have that move vertically, here's some code showing how I've done that. It's basically swapping the changes in x-coordinates to y-coordinates. I've adapted it to the current version of AndEngine, the original version of the code that targeted an old version can be found [here](http://www.andengine.org/forums/features/vertical-parallax-background-t1407.html).

```
import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.entity.IEntity;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.ParallaxBackground.ParallaxEntity;
import org.andengine.opengl.util.GLState;

public class VerticalParallaxEntity extends ParallaxEntity 
{
    final float mParallaxFactor;
    final IEntity mEntity;

    public VerticalParallaxEntity(final float pParallaxFactor, final IEntity pEntity) 
    {
        super(pParallaxFactor, pEntity);
        this.mParallaxFactor = pParallaxFactor;
        this.mEntity = pEntity;
    }

    public void onDraw(final GLState pGLState, final Camera pCamera, final float pParallaxValue) 
    {
        pGLState.pushModelViewGLMatrix();
        {
            final float cameraHeight = pCamera.getHeight();
            final float entityHeightScaled = this.mEntity.getHeight() * this.mEntity.getScaleY();

            float baseOffset = (pParallaxValue * this.mParallaxFactor) % entityHeightScaled;

            while(baseOffset > 0) {
                baseOffset -= entityHeightScaled;
            }
            pGLState.translateModelViewGLMatrixf(0, baseOffset, 0);

            float currentMaxY = baseOffset;

            do 
            {
                this.mEntity.onDraw(pGLState, pCamera);
                pGLState.translateModelViewGLMatrixf(0, entityHeightScaled, 0);
                currentMaxY += entityHeightScaled;
            } while(currentMaxY < cameraHeight);
        }
        pGLState.popModelViewGLMatrix();
    }
}
```